# Using Python how can I extract a version number from a shell output?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am still learning...

Using python I want to extract the version number from a shell output to determine if an upgrade is required.

I was able to use subprocess.call with `shell=true`, however i read this is a security issue and would like some advise on a better method.  I then hit an `AttributeError` as it seems `StrictVersion` doesn't see the output as a integer, I think?

Here is what I am doing currently.

```
import subprocess
from distutils.version import StrictVersion


def updateAnsible():
    print 'Checking Ansible version'
    version = subprocess.call("ansible --version | grep 'ansible [0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2 }'", shell=True)

    print version
    if StrictVersion(version) < StrictVersion('2.7.0'):
        print "Need to upgrade"
    else:
        print "Do not need to upgrade"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updateAnsible()
```

I Expect the output of StrictVersion(version) to be `1.2.3`

but what i get is the below

```
Checking Ansible version
1.2.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
0
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    updateAnsible()
  File "test.py", line 26, in updateAnsible
    if StrictVersion(version) < StrictVersion('2.6.0'):
  File "python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 140, in __cmp__
    compare = cmp(self.version, other.version)
AttributeError: StrictVersion instance has no attribute 'version'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: No security issues here because you aren't using string concatenation to pass variables into the command run with `shell=True`. Well, no big ones; if the shell has startup-time vulnerabilities like shellshock was you'd still be in trouble, but it's not nearly as bad as most `shell=True` uses are.

Comment: ...anyhow, I'd argue that there are two separate concerns: The capture, and the version comparison. Ideally, they should be distinct questions.

Comment: The immediate problem is that your capture process isn't getting the output of your shell pipeline; instead, it's returning the *exit status*, and that exit status isn't a string that `StrictVersion` can parse. The output is just being written by `grep` straight to the stdout it inherited when your script was started up.

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_output` instead of `subprocess.call` to fix the AttributeError.

Comment: BTW, in `[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]`, the `.`s aren't matched only against the period character -- they're wildcards in regex and match *any* character. And since it's common for a version number to be something like `2.14.3`, assuming each segment will only be one digit isn't necessarily well-founded. (For that matter, `2.1.3rc5` is possible too, so you can't even assume digits-only if you want to be robust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate and narrow issue is that `subprocess.call()` returns exit status (which will be `0` if the `grep` didn't fail, or `1` if it did), not output. This can be worked around by using `check_output()` instead:

```
version = subprocess.check_output(
    "ansible --version | awk '/ansible [0-9].[0-9].[0-9]/ { print $2; exit }'", shell=True
).strip().decode('utf-8')
```

If you want to avoid `shell=True` (commendable, but not actually an immediate security issue in your current use case), that might look like:

```
import re

av = subprocess.check_output(['ansible', '--version'])
match = re.match('^ansible (\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+)$', av.split(b'\n')[0].decode('utf-8'))
if match is None:
  raise Exception("Unable to get version number from ansible")
version = match.group(1)
```